# Constant of integration when using dummy variables

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

When reading about existence and uniqueness of various differential operators, I noticed that my textbook added a constant of integration when integrating using dummy variables:
[image]

### [image]

The book then proceeds to solve for the constants but I'm wondering, is it proper to include constants $C_1$ and $C_2$ when we are dealing with a seemingly definite integral?

Comment: @Aryadeva Partial Differential Equations - Analytical and Numerical Methods (2nd edition) by Mark Gockenbach. This particular example is from page 44.

Comment: Thank you ...... Vovnsons